# Hybrid Multi Module Maven Project with Spring Roo - Multiple JPA Persistence Units

Tags: maven, jpa, spring-roo, multi-module

I'm trying to create a hybrid multi-module maven project, where some projects are managed by Spring Roo and others are independent.

This is my project structure so far:

Root Project (root POM)
|
| -- **commons**   (maven module, Spring Roo Managed, JPA Persistence Module)
| -- **core**              (maven module, Spring Roo Managed, JPA Persistence Module)
| -- **backoffice** (maven module, Spring Roo Managed, WebApp)
| -- **frontoffice** (maven module, WebApp)

Maven dependencies:
 - Backoffice < Core < Commons
 
 - FrontOffice < Core < Commons

So far, so good. I can build my artifacts and manage the above projects using Spring Roo. 
However, since i'm using spring roo in both by persistence modules, i have two jpa persistence units. I would like to delegate that responsibility to the FrontOffice or BackkOffice web application, but, since the persistence modules are managed using Spring Roo, it needs to have the JPA configuration.

Do you have any suggestions on how to organize a multi-module maven project when some of the modules are Spring Roo managed?

Thanks for your help and advice's

Best Regards

JSimas

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not pointing the answer, but this might actually help.

http://labs.bsb.com/2010/11/configuring-modular-jpa-applications-with-spring/